# Use logging in Bash script

Tags: bash, logging

I have a bash script from which i need to write logs. currently i use block like the one below

```
#log stop request
            {
                local now=$(date +"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")

                printf "batch stop request successful. \n"
                printf "      Time            :: %s\n" "$now"
                printf "      PID of process  :: %s\n" ${PID[0]}"
            } >> "${mylogfile}"
```

where mylogfile variable will have name of the logfile.

The problem with this approach is that when 2 or more instances are running, the logs tends to get messed up with writes from instances coming interleaved.

Please note i used the block thinking that it would result in the log being written to file in one go, thus avoiding the problem.

I have seen logger command from [Vivek Gite post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html). but the problem is it does not write to a file I can specify, rather does so to /var/log/message.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Sibi

Comment: What happens if you group all the writing into a single `printf` statement?  What happens if you forego the multiple lines for a single message and use just one line for the whole message?

Comment: Does not work, still i get interleaved messages

Answer (score 3):

POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2001) does not define the behavior of concurrent [write()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write) syscalls sending data to the same file, hence you may obtain different results depending on your platform. You can try to merge all `printfs` into one in the hope that this will work, but even if it does there is no guarantee that it will in the future or on a different platform.

Rather than using concurrency control and flushing to ensure the writes are sequenced, you can send the messages to a third process which will write your log messages sequentially to a file on behalf on all the processes. In fact, this is what is done with `logger` and `syslog` in the [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html) you cited. The `logger` command does not send the messages to `/var/log/messages`. It sends the log messages to `syslog` which can be configured to save the log messages anywhere you like. Changing this configuration usually requires administrative privileges, though.

If you can't or don't want to use `syslog`, you can also use [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) as a logging server. Run this to multiplex all incoming log messages from all scripts into the file (this job should remain running in the background all the time, you can also run it in a [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)):

```
nc -luk localhost 9876 > shared_log_file &
```

(port 9876 is just an example) and log in each script this way:

```
printf "Log message\n" > /dev/udp/localhost/9876
```

You can also use a custom UDP server instead of netcat (e.g. like [this one](http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html)).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the great explanation. Any pointer on where i can get a sample for logger would be great. I tried the net but with no results.

Comment: I still think that's needlessly complex when he could just group his related printfs in a sub-shell and redirect its output, since he's not looking for a specific kind of logging behavior (e.g. through syslog(3)), he just wants "transactional" writes.

Comment: hi Adam and jkh, JKH is right am looking for transactional write. Thats to both of you for helping me

Comment: My understanding is that his printfs happen in unrelated processes. If he could group all these processes run under a common shell, then your solution is indeed simpler and does the job.

Comment: My printf happen in unrelated processes. Mine is a batch run script and more than one batch can be run in parallel writing to same log file.

Answer (score 2):

The block does not group the printfs in any way, as you have discovered.  What you could do, however, is do all of those commands in a sub-shell (between parenthesis) and then redirect the sub-shell's output!

Answer (score 1):

Trying putting the 3 printfs as one string, i.e.

```
printf "Epsilon batch stop request successful. \n      Time            :: %s\n     PID of process  :: %s\n" "$now"  ${PID[0]}
```

You may still get interleaving.

Why not start each instance with its own log file, using the ${PID} on your logfile name to keep them separate? i.e.

```
 >> "${mylogfile}.${PID}"
```

**Edit**

As you're hoping for logger, check out the man page :

```
logger(1) - Linux man page

Name

logger - a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module

Synopsis
logger [-isd] [-f file] [-p pri] [-t tag] [-u socket] [message ...]

Description

Logger makes entries in the system log. It provides a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module.

Options:

    -i'         Log the process id of the logger process with each line.
    -s' Log the message to standard error, as well as the system log.
    -f file
        Log the specified file.

.....
```

That looks like what you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi shellter , i have a restriction that I must log to one file. Is there a way I can use logger to write to a custom file?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of your logging, it might be well-suited for the system log instead of its private logfile. In this case, the `logger` program could be a very good alternative to hand-rolled logging.

Comment: I like this suggestion. There was no mention as to why the system log can't be used.

Comment: Hi phasetwenty, I have a requirement to log on a file at custom location.